# Unable to Play Widevine Encrypted Video in Exoplayer

Tags: android, encryption, exoplayer, widevine, bento

I have a Widevine DRM based encrypted video.
The video is encrypted using bento4 ,

mp4dash --widevine-header provider:widevine_test#content_id:2a --encryption-key 90351951686b5e1ba222439ecec1f12a:0a237b0752cbf1a827e2fecfb87479a2 video-source.mp4
Check this link for [more info](https://www.bento4.com/developers/dash/encryption-and-drm/)

Now I am trying to play this video on Android using Exoplayer and I am getting an error

> android.media.MediaCodec$CryptoException: Error decrypting data:
> requested key has not been loaded
>
> Error decrypting data: requested key has not been loaded

I have mpd file on my sdcard .I have tried to the simple mpd file (without encryption), it played successfully but I have tried a lot playing the encrypted video with key but I am unable to play .What is the right way to pass the key ?

Please guide me .Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set the widevine proxy correctly? (`https://proxy.uat.widevine.com/proxy?video_id=2a&provider=widevine_test` for example)

Comment: yes I added this in media.exolist.json   {
        "name": "Encrypted with key",
        "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/61385/61385.mpd",
        "drm_scheme": "widevine",
        "drm_license_url": "https://proxy.uat.widevine.com/proxy?provider=widevine_test"

      }

Comment: ok I just added it .and tried again........still same issue android.media.MediaCodec$CryptoException: Error decrypting data: requested key has not been loaded

Comment: how to pass the encryption key ?

Comment: I tested with `shaka-player` and the `video_id` is not needed. If you have access to an actual web server to host the files you could try to see if it works [here](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com).

Comment: I tested on shaka player, video is playing

Comment: Do you have any idea to play MPEG DASH encrypted video in exoplayer

Comment: What happens if you use the hosted manifest in `media.exolist.json` instead of using the sdcard? Try the same options that worked in shaka-player.

Comment: If you have any demo example ..please provide me